# Why am I not getting the V1 and V2 Signature versions checkboxes when i create a APK in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

[image]

I have the latest version of android studio installed and and also the latest Java version installed

Answer (score 2):

Found it! I have adjusted my gradle file like so:

```
signingConfigs {
mySigningConfig {
    keyAlias 'theAlias'
    keyPassword 'thePassword'
    storeFile file('theKeystore.jks')
    storePassword 'thePassword'
    v1SigningEnabled true
    v2SigningEnabled true
}
```

}